# How can I submit a form without redirecting and without using an iframe? (Doesn't seem to work on mobile devices)

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

My submit works perfectly on my desktop without redirect using an iframe. When accessing my site via mobile device (chrome & safari) the page redirects to the endpoint and halts.  I would like a mobile friendly way to stop the redirect.

```html
<iframe width="0" height="0" border="0" name="dummyframe" id="dummyframe"></iframe>

<form id="upload-form" action="http://10.121.86.136:5000/upload" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" target="dummyframe">

<input @click="send_img()" name="submit" type="submit" value="Upload Image">

send_img() {

      var url_1 = "http://10.121.86.136:5000/send_images"

      axios.post(url_1, ...)

      ...
}


The results on mobile is a blank screen at the endpoint ip:5000/send_images
```

Answer (score 0):

you can't constrain the iframe itself with height and width. You should put a div around it. If you control the content in the iframe, you can put some JS within the iframe content that will tell the parent to scroll the div when the touch event is received.

Answer (score 0):

10 dots are private networks. Make sure your mobile device is connected to same network as desktop or application. Where do you want to be redirected? You could just redirect to the same page. Your form is coded to submit post to http://10.121.86.136:5000/upload; but looks like your adding an additional redirect with button click. Id recommend setting url_1 equal to where you want to end.

Comment: You are correct I am sending an axios post in a method call at the same time as I submit the form (referencing a different endpoint without a redirect) they go different places with different objectives.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<form id="upload-form" action="http://10.121.86.136:5000/upload" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" target="dummyframe">

<input  name="submit" type="submit" value="Upload Image">


 $("#upload-form").submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

  var url_1 = "http://10.121.86.136:5000/send_images"

      axios.post(url_1, ...)

      ...

      });
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to work as intended now, I did not change anything and I am not sure what it was doing yesterday but the mobile upload no longer redirects and gets hung up on the endpoint.